# Set a:link / a:visited colors within another css call

Tags: css, forum

Not sure if my semantics are correct. On my forum, I have a way my links look that looks good in a regular post, but doesn't when someone is quoted in a post, the text is shrunk down to a smaller font and it doesn't look good.

So I tried this, but it had no effect at all.

```
    blockquote {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 4px;
font-size: 11px;
a:link {color:#00FF00;}
}
blockquote cite {
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-style: normal;
    display: block;
    margin: 4px 0;
font-size: 11px;
a:link {color:#00FF00;}
}
```

Is there anything I can do to easily change the link properties here? Because the way I'm trying it doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: Your question starts off talking about quotes, but at the end talks about links..?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest css rules like this:

```
blockquote cite {
    a:link {  }
}
```

you would use this:

```
blockquote cite {

}
blockquote cite a:link {
    /* rules for links within 'blockquote cite' */
}
```

With invalid css some of your other rules may not work, and it can cause other unexpected formatting issues.

Comment: To be honest, this is fundamental to css, so perhaps you should take the time to go through a tutorial.

Comment: Darn, this is taking over other links on the page. The links within the regular post part and links even outside the post at the top of the forum are being hi-jacked by the blockquote cite a:link color.

Comment: Rules within `blockquote cite a:link { }` will *only* affect links within blockquote, then cite elements. Use the [css validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input)

Comment: Yes. The CSS is 100%. You can see chinaphonearena.com, though for now I've removed the color changing for cite. It was changing even the Forum names in the main forum. I was changing a:visited as well in the same line. I don't know if that's a problem or not. `blockquote cite a:link,a:visited {color:#00FF00}`

Comment: That will change ALL visited links because of the comma. `blockquote cite a:link, blockquote cite a:visited`. Again, I recommend that you take a tutorial as this is fundamental to css as well.

Comment: Andy, thanks for helping out, but I just wanted to leave a big kiss my ass to Stackoverflow, you uppity geeked out twits.